# Pin strength configuration

Tags: fpga, configuration, microsemi-fpga, drive-strength

Please, help me understand the [specsheet](https://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_view/130702-ds0100-proasic3l-low-power-flash-fpgas-datasheet) on page 2-22. The table says that 3.3V standard supports 12mA drive strength, but there is also a "software" defined strength. What is it? There is also a "wide range" (table 2-29 second row, and notes 1 and 2). How do I know if my FPGA is set to wide range or not? The settings in the IO interactive tool (see below) do not provide this information. In fact, bank3 allows me to select 16mA and 24mA as well. How do I interpret all this information and apply? Specifically, it seems like my FPGA is operating in the wide range mode and thus I get only 100uA drive strength even if the setting says 12mA.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have not used this software, but I would look to the "I/O Standard" setting. Hover over it or widen the column until you can read the setting- it probably says "wide range" in the hidden part to the right.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany The IO Standard screenshot attached - no wide range spec.

Comment: Turning on additional FET stripes gives incremental boost to drive strength. Could be with extra TRI-STATE outputs, or gated Nch and Pch stripes.